# Exception in Tkinter callback: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x, tkinter, exception

I am getting the error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`, in my small Python program (on Jupyter Notebook), preventing me from actually calculating the currency.

It's supposed to be a simple currency converter application; However when I use the calculation code inside the 'convert' function then I get the above error, otherwise outside a function then the code nicely retrieves the data using the API key and the currency is converted.

Thank you all in advance for any help, also since I'm really new, any other advice on my code (that is not perhaps done in the *pythonic way*) would be greatly appreciated.

### Error:

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-41-161d07d3ddae>", line 29, in convert
    currency_Collection = json.loads(str(r.text))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

### Code:

```
#-------------Imports
import requests
import json

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#-------------Variables
value_ToConvert = float()
value_Converted = float()

currencyBase_ToConvert  = ''
currencyBase_Converted = ''

countries = ['ALL: Albania [Lek]','AMD: Armenia [Armenian Dram]','ANG: Curaço [Netherlands Antillean Guilder]','AOA: Angola [Kwanza]','ARS: Argentina [Argentine Peso]','AUD: Australia [Australian Dollar]','AZN: Azerbaijan [Azerbaijanian Manat]','BBD: Barbados [Barbados Dollar]','BDT: Bangladesh [Taka]','BGN: Bulgaria [Bulgarian Lev]','BHD: Bahrain [Bahraini Dinar]','BRL: Brazil [Brazilian Real]','BSD: Bahamas [Bahamian Dollar]','BWP: Botswana [Pula]','BYN: Belarus [Belarusian Ruble]','CAD: Canada [Canadian Dollar]','CDF: Congo [Franc Congolais]','CLP: Chile [Chilean Peso]','CNY: China [Yuan Renminbi]','COP: Colombia [Colombian Peso]','CZK: Czech Republic [Czech Koruna]','DKK: Denmark [Danish Krone]','DOP: Dominican Republic [Dominican Peso]','EGP: Egypt [Egyptian Pound]','ETB: Ethiopia [Ethiopian Birr]','EUR: Åland Islands [Euro]','FJD: Fiji [Fiji Dollar]','GBP: Guernsey [Pound Sterling]','GEL: Georgia [Lari]','GHS: Ghana [Ghana Cedi]','GTQ: Guatemala [Quetzal]','HKD: Hong Kong [Hong Kong Dollar]','HNL: Honduras [Lempira]','HRK: Croatia [Croatian Kuna]','HUF: Hungary [Forint]','IDR: Indonesia [Rupiah]','ILS: Israel [New Israeli Sheqel]','INR: India [Indian Rupee]','IQD: Iraq [Iraqi Dinar]','IRR: Iran, Islamic Republic Of [Iranian Rial]','ISK: Iceland [Iceland Krona]','JMD: Jamaica [Jamaican Dollar]','JOD: Jordan [Jordanian Dinar]','JPY: Japan [Yen]','KES: Kenya [Kenyan Shilling]','KHR: Cambodia [Riel]','KRW: Korea, Republic of [Won]','KWD: Kuwait [Kuwaiti Dinar]','KZT: Kazakhstan [Tenge]','LAK: Lao Peoples Democratic Republic [Kip]','LBP: Lebanon [Lebanese Pound]','LKR: Sri Lanka [Sri Lanka Rupee]','MAD: Morocco [Moroccan Dirham]','MDL: Moldova, Republic of [Moldovan Leu]','MKD: Macedonia [Denar]','MMK: Myanmar [Kyat]','MUR: Mauritius [Mauritius Rupee]','MXN: Mexico [Mexican Peso]','MYR: Malaysia [Malaysian Ringgit]','NAD: Namibia [Namibia Dollar]','NGN: Nigeria [Naira]','NOK: Norway [Norwegian Krone]','NZD: New Zealand [New Zealand Dollar]','OMR: Oman [Rial Omani]','PAB: Panama [Balboa]','PEN: Peru [Nuevo Sol]','PGK: Papua New Guinea [Kina]','PHP: Philippines [Philippine Peso]','PKR: Pakistan [Pakistan Rupee]','PLN: Poland [Zloty]','PYG: Paraguay [Guarani]','QAR: Qatar [Qatari Rial]','RON: Romania [New Romanian Leu]','RSD: Serbia [Serbian Dinar]','RUB: Russian Federation [Russian Ruble]','SAR: Saudi Arabia [Saudi Riyal]','SCR: Seychelles [Seychelles Rupee]','SEK: Sweden [Swedish Krona]','SGD: Singapore [Singapore Dollar]','THB: Thailand [Baht]','TJS: Tajikistan [Somoni]','TND: Tunisia [Tunisian Dinar]','TRY: Turkey [New Turkish Lira]','TTD: Trinidad and Tobago [Trinidad and Tobago Dollar]','TWD: Taiwan, Province of China [New Taiwan Dollar]','TZS: Tanzania [Tanzanian Shilling]','UAH: Ukraine [Hryvnia]','USD: United States [US Dollar]','UYU: Uruguay [Peso Uruguayo]','UZS: Uzbekistan [Uzbekistan Sum]','VEF: Venezuela [Bolivar]','VND: Viet Nam [Dong]','XAF: Cameroon [CFA Franc BEAC ‡]','XCD: Anguilla [East Caribbean Dollar]','XOF: Benin [CFA Franc BCEAO †]','XPF: French Polynesia [CFP Franc]','ZAR: South Africa [Rand]','ZMW: Zambia [Kwacha]']

#-------------Definitions

try:
    def convert():
        value_ToConvert = value_entry.get()
        currencyBase_ToConvert = currencyBase_ToConvert_Box.get()
        currencyBase_Converted = currencyBase_Converted_Box.get()

        currencyBase_Parameter = '/' + currencyBase_ToConvert
        r = requests.get('https://v3.exchangerate-api.com/bulk/b76715d91ecbbc9c14a229e8' + currencyBase_Parameter)

        currency_Collection = dict()
        currency_Collection = json.loads(r.text)
        currency_Rates = dict(currency_Collection['rates'])
        value_Converted = float(value_ToConvert) * float(currency_Rates[currencyBase_Converted])
        print (value_Converted)
        currencyBase_Converted_Label = ttk.Label(mainframe, text = value_Converted).grid(column = 3, row = 2, stick = W, padx = 10, pady = 20)
except Exception:
    print(Exception)

def reset():
    value_ToConvert = 0.0
    value_Converted = 0.0

    currencyBase_ToConvert = ''
    currencyBase_Converted = ''

    currencyBase_ToConvert_Box.set("")
    currencyBase_Converted_Box.set("")
    return

def exit():
    root.destroy()
    return

#-------------Creating Frame
root = Tk()
root.title("Currency Converter")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
root.geometry ('350x200+0+0')
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

#Row: 1
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "HAVE").grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = (N,W), padx = 10, pady = 20)

currencyBase_ToConvert_Box = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable = currencyBase_ToConvert, state = 'readonly')
currencyBase_ToConvert_Box['values'] = countries
currencyBase_ToConvert_Box.current(0)
currencyBase_ToConvert_Box.grid(column = 2, row = 1, padx = 0, pady = 20)
currencyBase_ToConvert_Box.set("")

value_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 10, textvariable = value_ToConvert)
value_entry.grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = (N,E), padx = 10, pady = 20)

#Row: 2
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "WANT").grid(column = 1, row = 2, stick = W, padx = 10, pady = 20)

currencyBase_Converted_Box = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable = currencyBase_Converted, state = 'readonly')
currencyBase_Converted_Box['values'] = countries
currencyBase_Converted_Box.current(0)
currencyBase_Converted_Box.grid(column = 2, row = 2, padx = 0, pady = 20)
currencyBase_Converted_Box.set("")

#Row: 3
btnConvert = Button(mainframe, text = "Convert", padx = 40, pady = 20, width = 1, height = 1, command = convert).grid(column = 1, row = 3)
btnReset = Button(mainframe, text = "Reset", padx = 40, pady = 20, width = 1, height = 1, command = reset).grid(column = 2, row = 3)
btnExit = Button(mainframe, text = "Exit", padx = 40, pady = 20, width = 1, height = 1, command = exit).grid(column = 3, row = 3)

root.mainloop()
```

I added a picture to help illustrate what I'm trying to accomplice, the output (that is created once the 'convert' button is activated) should be below the top right label, in: column 3; row 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7368.png)

Comment: Try to post slightly less code where possible. See [mcve].

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Thank you! You're right, I could've taken out at least 1/3 or even 2/5. I have bookedmarked the link that you provided and I will definitely refer to it before posting another post.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Thank you once again, I was about to ask the StackOverFlow community another question; However, after reading the links that you provided and using the MCVE approach I actually solved my problem before I even had to post anything.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you use a wrong data, edit like this:

```
def convert():
    value_ToConvert = value_entry.get()
    currencyBase_ToConvert = currencyBase_ToConvert_Box.get().split(':')[0]
    currencyBase_Converted = currencyBase_Converted_Box.get().split(':')[0]
```

API uses only currency codes, but you pass all your text (like **AUD: Australia [Australian Dollar]**, but you need only **AUD**)

Comment: Thank you!! I've been on this error for 1-2 days and now I just want to kick myself for not realizing this. I thought to make it easier for the user with the extra information, but I obviously didn't take everything else into consideration. Thank you once again for your time and effort, I upvoted your comment, but I don't have enough reputation for it to be publicly displayed.